# Floating number subtraction issue in php

Tags: php

I am having a floating number subtraction issue.

This is my code:

```
  $totalEarning = number_format($bsal+$attn+$incen+$tran+$otdpay+$othpay, 2); // 41,256.25
  $totalDed     = number_format($adv+$stmp+$insu+$nopay+$other+$emplyepf, 2); // 4,436.60   
  $netSalary    = number_format($totalEarning - $totalDed, 2);
```

But in `$netSalary` have a different output. My expecting result is `36819.65`, but it gives this `37.00`.

Can anybody tell me what is the wrong with my code?

Comment: Don't try adding ___after___ formatting with thousnds separators; add the raw values

Comment: @MarkBaker, you mean like this `$netSalary    = $totalEarning - $totalDed; ` ?

Comment: No, I mean calculating `$totalEarning`, `$totalDed` ___and___ $netSalary without any use of `number_format()`, only use `number_format()` at the point of display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Mark Baker means:

```
$totalEarning = $bsal+$attn+$incen+$tran+$otdpay+$othpay;
$totalDed     = $adv+$stmp+$insu+$nopay+$other+$emplyepf;  
$netSalary    = $totalEarning - $totalDed;

echo number_format($netSalary, 2);
```